# Add content to the top of an HTML file with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

How can I add text to the top of an HTML file with Powershell? 
So far I tried the code below, but it appends the text to the end of the file.

```bsh
Add-Content -Path $htmlfile -Value $text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this script to prepend text to the HTML below:

```bsh
param(
    [string] $pathToHtml = "$PSScriptRoot\index.html",
    [string] $contentToAdd = '<!doctype html>'
)

$html = Get-Content -Path $pathToHtml
$html
Set-Content -Path $pathToHtml -Value ($contentToAdd + $html)
$html
```

HTML

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This does just what I wanted, perfect! Thanks a lot!